# Is scanning a site directory considered illegal penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test, http, legal, web-scanners

Does anyone know if using Dirbuster [[link]](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_DirBuster_Project) to scan for unlisted directories and their contents is (possibly) legal in say the US?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have permission to perform security testing against a target, don't do it.

In the US, you are definitely at risk of falling foul of the [The Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](http://www.panix.com/~eck/computer-fraud-act.html) 1986, 1994, 1996 and possibly other acts. It's easy enough to set up a test target of your own, ask a friend for permission to test their site, or use a service such as Webgoat or Gruyere.

Essentially, if you are seen to be someone who knows what you are doing, then even typing in a single-quote to a web form has been enough to be arrested and charged over in the past.

No permission, no pen testing. It's simple. Why risk it.

Comment: To be honest I'm curious about a site in the making, and I kinda wanted to take a sneak peek seen as the directories are fully unprotected. xD I could just hide myself behind proxies but I think I'll do the right thing and pass. =)

Comment: @Happy, judges don't tend to treat "I was just curious" as extenuating circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You should only test on software you own or have written consent to test on. If you wan't to "play" and test there are a lot of options. One such good one is the [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) . [Here](http://www.ehacking.net/2011/11/how-to-install-damn-vulnerable-web-app.html) is even a script to get the entire thing up and running in a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @Cheekysoft, basically using any knowledge over and above point and click is ilegal unless youve got it in writing from the legal owners of the target/client systems. It's meant to be vague as technology moves infinitely faster than legislation.

Comment: in fact i'm almost 100% certain that anyone working in technology except the cleaning ladies are technically criminals