# Are SQL injection scans considered illegal?

Tags: penetration-test, legal

I know that this [thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14978/is-scanning-a-site-directory-considered-illegal-penetration-testing) mentions that

> Essentially, if you are seen to be someone who knows what you are
>   doing, then even typing in a single-quote to a web form has been
>   enough to be arrested and charged over in the past.

But lets say i'm writing a pen test tool that will be doing sqli testing and let it loose on sites that are 'out in the wild'. I'm not going to be doing dumps of any information. But is just the vulnerability scan itself illegal?

Comment: While we, as security professionals, do often have to deal closely with legal issues, we're not here to serve up legal advice. This kind of question in particular is highly localized since it depends exclusively on jurisdictional boundaries.

Comment: Instead of worrying about legality, just make sure you don't get caught. Use Tor and make sure you hide all your unique browser identifiers or use a proxy that removes them (Privoxy I think). I think it's all in one package now if you download Tor bundle.

Comment: Geez. Don't listen to Matrix. One of the hallmarks of a real security professional is a high ethical and moral standard. You must consider if you "should" more than you consider if you "can."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will depend on the legal system under which it falls. But you are still doing something hostile. Without previous written permission of the siteowner, you are committing a crime.

There is no way of proving you didn't have a malicious **intent**. Intent is the key component here. A ping can be done to see if your own internet connection is working or if a website might be down because of a failing server. But if your intent is the see if a site/server is vulnerable for a ping fload, then you are possible already committing a felony.

It will be up for a judge to decide, but consider this:

If you would be trying all the doors of a random car in the street to see it's properly locked and someone sees that, would they believe you were just trying to see if it's locked?

Comment: Would a 'ping' fall under the "trying the door handles" situation?

Comment: Like I said that's up for a judge to decide. With a vulnerability scan you are going way further than just one ping.

Comment: I can test a website with just a quotation mark in the url or a form. Isn't this comparable to "just one ping"?

Comment: We are getting into a discussion, which is more approriate for the chat. But like I said, that's up for a JUDGE TO DECIDE.

Comment: Plus if your intent is the see if the site is vulnerable, that would be considered hostile.

Comment: In France for example, not allowed access, or maintained presence in an Information System is considered illegal. Trying to do that is considered to be as illegal as actually doing it.

Comment: ^ counts as well for Belgium

Comment: If it is easy as a mouse click and hitting a button in keyboard, i would believe.